# Программа выдает неверный результат (0)

Tags: c

Суть в том, что у нас есть массив, где первые 2 элемента равняются 0, а третий равняется 1.5. Далее идет формула, по которой просчитывается следующий член массива. В начале программы мы просим пользователя ввести n (количество элемента массива (>=4)). Задача программы - найти числовое значение n ого элемента массива. Почему-то при любых значениях выводит 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int i, n;
printf ("Enter n ");
scanf ("%d", &n);
float ar [n];
if(n>=4){
ar[0]=0;
ar[1]=0;
ar[2]=1.5;
for (i=3; i < n; i++){
ar[i]=(i+1.0 + 1)/(((i+1.0)*(i+1.0)+1)*ar[i-1])-ar[i-2]*ar[i-3];
}
printf ("%f", ar[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Опять эта ошибка. Вам нужно читать `n` ДО создания массива `float ar [n];`. После создания массива, изменение `n` ни на что не влияет.

Comment: Что такое `float ar[n];` когда значение `n` не инициализировано???

Comment: Уже отредактировал, тут другая проблема

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отформатируем вашу программу:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i, n;
    float ar [n];
    printf("Enter n ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n >= 4) {
        ar[0] = 0;
        ar[1] = 0;
        ar[2] = 1.5;

        for (i = 3; i < n; i++) {
            ar[i] = (i + 1.0 + 1) / (((i + 1.0) * (i + 1.0) + 1) * ar[i - 1]) -
                    ar[i - 2] * ar[i - 3];
            }

        printf("%f", ar[i]);
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

И сразу видим, что вы выводите не в цикле, а после него, т.е. только одно (не существующее) значение.

Перенесите

```
        printf("%f", ar[i]);
```

выше, в цикл.

И выделяйте массив после того, как узнаете его размер, а не до -

```
printf ("Enter n ");
scanf ("%d", &n);
float ar [n];
```

Comment: И добавьте в выводе `\n` или пробел, а то сливаться числа будут :)

Comment: Это конечно все хорошо, но мне нужно вывести именно последний член массива, поэтому я и вывел printf за цикл.

Comment: Это конечно все хорошо, но мне нужно вывести именно последний член массива, поэтому я и вывел printf за цикл. А с массивом уже исправил проблему.

Comment: Все равно вы выводите не то. Последнее `i`, для которого вы посчитали элемент массива - это `n-1`. Потом в цикле происходит очедерное увеличение `i`, оно становится равным `n`, выход из цикла - и в результате, выводя `ar[i]`, вы пытаетесь вывести `ar[n]`, которого у вас нет и близко! Хотите вывести ппоследний член массива - выводите просто `printf("%f", ar[n-1]);`. Еще раз - после выхода из цикла `i` равно `n`, а в массиве у вас элементы от `0` до `n-1`.

Comment: Все, спасибо, понял